# Hard summation involving one integer variable

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, numerical-methods

How can I compute the value of
$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \cdot \frac{(n+1)!^n(1+(2+n) \cdot n!^n) + n!^{n-1}}{(1 + n!^n)(1 + (n+1)!^{n+1})}?$$

Numerical experiments show that the value of this sum may be equal to $\frac 12$, but I can't find any evidence.

Comment: What is the motivation and source of such a monster sum?